# Retrieving utf-8 data with jQuery.get

Tags: jquery, utf-8, codemirror

I'm retrieving using jQuery to retrieve a text file from the server and load into the code mirror editor.  (This is in Chrome)

When I have a test file with the following test string:

üöIiçgIös

It is displayed as:

s��Ii�gI�s

I load the data with a jQuery.get() call.  Using Chrome's script debugger,  I can see that  jQuery is transforming the data somehow, basically translating it (poorly) into ASCII.

I've confirmed using a direct download the right data is loaded.  Using Fiddler, I confirmed the content type is "text/plain;charset=UTF-8".  Finally, I can see from the menu that the page as a whole has encoding UTF-8.  But I can't figure out why jQuery is transforming the data.

Here's my jQuery code to load the data.

```
jQuery.get(path+file,null,function(data)
{
  var initialContent = data;
  if(!initialContent)
  {
    initialContent = "\n";
  } 

  document.getElementById("fileContent").value = initialContent;
  config.content = data,
  editor = new CodeMirror(document.getElementById("codeMirrorDiv"), config);
},'text');
```

Comment: "I've confirmed using a direct download the right data is loaded" - the browser's character set detection is at UTF-8 when you call the URL? It is not jumping to ISO-8859-x or something else? You are 100% sure?

Comment: I meant that when I enter the URL directly in the address bar, and download the file, saving to disk, I confirm the right bytes were loaded.

Comment: can you load the URL directly and see what encoding the browser switches to?

Comment: Whats the output if you try `$ file -bi test.txt`? It should be `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery for several years, and have never seen it "transform" data as you describe. I'm not sure that is even possible.

Make sure the page where the data is *displayed* has this in the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Also, make sure that when you edit your text file, you're actually editing it in UTF-8.

Comment: it does.  very strange.  I'll continue to tinker with this.  maybe I'm misinterpreting the path of the data through the layers.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is because of wrong data from your database.
Try to add these commands after connecting to the database:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'");
```

If this is not helping then try to add this header in the php file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Its good to know that any file (php, html...) have to be in utf-8 encoding. Easiest way to do that is:

- Open file with notepad
- File -> Save As
- Before saving choose encoding at bottom drop down list
- Done!

Answer (score -1):

If encoding and header is set and still data is incorrect then, probably, problem is in server side (PHP, JAVA, ...). **Check all string manipulation functions at server side.**

For PHP:

```
$WRONG_string = substr($string, 0, 10);
$CORRECT_string = mb_substr($string,0,10,'utf-8');
```

If You are using other server side language as PHP then you should check function manual for string encoding.